# Bind All data in Jquery Datatables from View To Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

Im binding my Data in View to Controller, so later I could do what I want with the data. In my View, im using `dataTable` and `@Html.EditorForModel()` to render my View.

View

```
<form action="xx" method="POST">
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Field1)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Field2)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Field3)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        @Html.EditorForModel()
    }
    </tbody>
    <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Script

```
$("#myTable").dataTable({
        searching: false,
        ordering: false,
        responsive: true,
        "bLengthChange" : false,
        "pageLength": 20,
        "bStateSave": true
    });
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(List<MyModel> MyListModel)
```

This method works great if the data is no more than 1 page in `dataTables`. if its more than 1 page, then My Controller either only can receive the `List Data` of the first page or receive nothing(null)

How should I bind all of my data in `DataTables` from View to Controller? This binding should include all pages, not only the first one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm unsure how you're triggering the update of data, so assuming it's a button the following should work:

```
$('#your-button').on('click', function(e){
   var data = ('#myTable').DataTable().$('input,select,textarea').serialize();

   $.ajax({
      url: '/MyController/MyAction/',
      data: data,
      success: function(){
         alert('success');
      }, 
      error: function(){
         alert('failure');
      }
   });
});
```

**Edit 1:**

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31420279/5309534) answer to [How to post data for the whole table using jQuery DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31418047/how-to-post-data-for-the-whole-table-using-jquery-datatables), if you're set on using a form use the following:

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();

$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){
   var form = this;

   var params = table.$('input,select,textarea').serializeArray();

   $.each(params, function(){
      if(!$.contains(document, form[this.name])){
         $(form).append(
            $('<input>')
               .attr('type', 'hidden')
               .attr('name', this.name)
               .val(this.value)
         );
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: by using `DataTable().$('input,select,textarea')`, its a good way to get all the data and input inside. But, I would rather to bind my data rather than using AJAX

Comment: Unless you're using a form how do you expect to bind your data? You're using a third party library to store your data on the DOM - the most efficient and safe way to handle this would be serialized AJAX calls.

Comment: oopss sorry if I didnt include it in my question. Im using form with a submit button. I have edited my question

Comment: In that case it looks like your question is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31418047). IMO opinion AJAX is the better option in this situation rather than creating invisible elements within the form.

Comment: OMG, i really had no idea there was a duplicate question to mine. what kind of meta word did u use to find that question? I googled for days and ended up nothing. Well, in my case, by using AJAX means I need to change all of my codes. So I prefer to `append` invisible elements to the form. If you want to add the answer with `append` function to the form, I will accept your answer.

Comment: "jquery datatable post" in Google - fourth result down!

Answer (score 2):

since you don't want any ajax 
Use [Javascript Source Data](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html), Pass your model to the view, serialize it, and use it as your source

```
var myData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ListOfData));

//then pass it to the datatable   

$('#example').DataTable( {
        data: myData,
        columns: [
            { title: "col1" },
            { title: "col2" },
           etc ... 
        ]
    } );
```

Answer (score 1):

With DataTables, only the current page data exist in the DOM. If you submit the form, only the current page data are being submitted back in the server. One solution to this is submit the data via ajax:

```
var myTable = $('#myTable').DataTable();

$('#your-form').on('submit', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   //serialize your data
   var data = myTable.$('input,select,textarea').serialize();

   $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action('MyAction', 'MyController')',
      data: data,
      success: function(responseData){
         //do whatever you want with the responseData
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Isn't this nearly exactly what I answered with?

Comment: by using `DataTable().$('input,select,textarea')`, its a good way to get all the data and input inside. But, I would rather to bind my data rather than using AJAX

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the data() method to get the data for the whole table:

```
$('#your-form').on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
  var data = table.data();

  $.ajax({
    url: '/MyController/MyAction/',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json;",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function(){
       alert('success');
    }, 
    error: function(){
       alert('failure');
    }
  });
```

Comment: `dataTable` and `DataTable` are two different things. to use `DataTable` functions, should use `dataTable.api()`. But the same with other answer, i would rather use Bind data method rather than AJAX

Answer (score 1):

Please go through following link

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part